# Is possible to split TextView to two triangular areas?

Tags: android, android-widget

How to create triangular TextView ( to llok like half of rectangle ) like on image 
[image]

I need to split one TextView ( rectangular shape to two complement triangular textviews)
like 
[image]

Is this possible at all, can somebody give me advice how to do this ?

Comment: Could you provide full picture of idea? Where will be second text? And what if text will be long?

Answer (score 0):

Use a proper background for that textview and you should be able to achieve this. Use a 9-patch image which specifies the proper padding and the areas to be marked as stretchable.